# How to disable static friction in Box2D?

Tags: physics, libgdx, box2d, platformer

I'm making a 2D platformer. One of the issues is that when the character hits the ground, there's an initial pause and then the character finally slows down to a halt. I believe the initial pause is because the coefficient of static friction is higher than the coefficient of kinetic friction. How can I set the coefficients to be equal or disable static friction?

Comment: Although the difference between static friction and kinetic friction is often made in high-school physics, it is not made in box2d. This question needs a little more detail for us to help you. Does this happen when a character is jumping or walking? What fixtures are in contact here? Screenshots/gifs/videos would be much appreciated.